# Not receiving events on Asterisk 11 AMI

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'm a veteran of Asterisk 1.4 and am looking to build a new application on Asterisk 11 (which is currently beta, but is planned to be LTS release some time before I need it.)

I can't get Asterisk Manager Interface on 11 to send me any events.  (Now, obviously, in production, I need to cut down these AMI rights drastically, but as I'm exploring I've opened the firehose, if you will.)

`manager.conf` looks like this:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 127.0.0.1

[manager]
secret = squirrel
deny = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit = 127.0.0.1/255.0.0.0
read = all
write = all
```

I then use `telnet` to try to get in and explore the event stream:

```
$ telnet localhost 5038
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Asterisk Call Manager/1.3
Action: Login
Username: manager
Secret: squirrel
Events: on

Response: Success
Message: Authentication accepted

Event: FullyBooted
Privilege: system,all
Status: Fully Booted
```

...and there it sits, not moving, no matter what I actually do with the system.  I've also tried using [the Event manager action](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_Events) with `EventMask: on` to try to get something out of it; the command is accepted, but nothing changes.  It will happily respond to any [other actions](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+AMI+Actions) I send it, though.

Any leads?  This sort of thing worked fine under 1.4, and I'm not finding anything in any documentation suggesting I'm doing something wrong.  I suppose the next thing to try is 1.8...

(There is little else in `/etc/asterisk`; I'm using example configs only for reference.  This is as minimal as we get...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this with the latest 11 from subversion using your configs.  I see events being generated.  For example, executing this from the CLI:

```
*CLI> channel originate Local/Foo application Bar
```

While invalid, will cause some events to be spit out to the manager interface.

Comment: Wow, this is flat-out **bizarre**.  As a last-ditch effort, I trimmed comments from `confbridge.conf` and did a `service asterisk restart` and suddenly the firehose is gushing, including with your example.  I wonder what the heck was going on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's may be bug in Asteriks / FreePBX. I had same situation, and my API php script didn't receive any events from AMI. 
For fix this bug, you must install "Conferences" module and restart Asterisk from SSH: service asterisk restart